# emacs-request formatting data returned and isolating data

Tags: list, emacs, python-requests, twitch

Hi I've been playing around with emacs-request in hopes of making an emacs package, but I've been running into some issues isolating and manipulating the alist's that are returned my emacs-request, my code is as follows:

```
(setq xbuff (generate-new-buffer "*my output*"))

(request
 "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed"
 :sync t
 :headers '(
        ("Accept" . "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json")
        ("Client-ID" . "XXX")
        ("Authorization" . "OAuth XXX"))
 :parser 'json-read
 :complete (cl-function
        (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
          (print data xbuff))))

(switch-to-buffer xbuff)
```

Currently I have this setup to send the retrieved and converted JSON data to a temporary buffer. I was wondering how I could isolate the data to make a well formatted list that would display specific attributes, if the stream is live.

For 1. a stream is considered live if it has the stream_live attribute
2. I want it to then grab username, game being played, and viewer count and display it in a neatly formatted mode such as this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbehE.png)

Comment: For those interested in getting a Twitch client-ID, and OAuth you can get them here: https://dev.twitch.tv/ an oauth can be retrieved here https://twitchapps.com/tmi/ make sure you remove the "oauth:" part when putting it in the Authorization field

Comment: The parsed json is in `data`, it's usually a list, you should be able to extract info from it.

Comment: This issue is the parsed data is in the form of an alist, making a bit difficult and confusing in terms of how to sort it properly.

Comment: Alist is the most common choice for dictionary, since alist is list and list is the primary type in Lisp, and you have many tools to manipulate list. Try to describe what probelm you can't solve, be specific, and provide real runnable sample code.

Comment: Sure let me give an output of what is returned from the code I provided above, perhaps it'll be a bit easier to visualize

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the returned formatted JSON that is given by the code snippet that I provided:

```
((streams . [((_id . 2309090545) (game . "Fall Guys") (broadcast_platform . "live") (community_id . "") (community_ids . []) (viewers . 43707) (video_height . 1080) (average_fps . 60) (delay . 0) (created_at . "2020-07-25T19:47:59Z") (is_playlist . :json-false) (stream_type . "live") (preview (small . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_xqcow-80x45.jpg") (medium . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_xqcow-320x180.jpg") (large . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_xqcow-640x360.jpg") (template . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_xqcow-{width}x{height}.jpg")) (channel (mature . :json-false) (status . "INTERGALACTIC WARLORD OBLITERATES THE COMPETITION") (broadcaster_language . "en") (broadcaster_software . "") (display_name . "xQcOW") (game . "Fall Guys") (language . "en") (_id . 71092938) (name . "xqcow") (created_at . "2014-09-12T23:50:05.989719Z") (updated_at . "2020-07-25T22:44:05.849527Z") (partner . t) (logo . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/xqcow-profile_image-9298dca608632101-300x300.jpeg") (video_banner . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/e1d84cfb-3b67-4f5b-8e3c-4fd3a97cc85f-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png") (profile_banner . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c0982a57-1d9d-47e1-8058-b2b1e0ebfcf1-profile_banner-480.jpg") (profile_banner_background_color . "") (url . "https://www.twitch.tv/xqcow") (views . 168347935) (followers . 3262754) (broadcaster_type . "") (description . "Overwatch Professional tank player and full time streamer. EZ Clap") (private_video . :json-false) (privacy_options_enabled . :json-false))) ((_id . 2.7623861885779876e+18) (game . "C.H.A.S.E.D.") (broadcast_platform . "live") (community_id . "") (community_ids . []) (viewers . 22082) (video_height . 1080) (average_fps . 60) (delay . 0) (created_at . "2020-07-25T21:28:53Z") (is_playlist . :json-false) (stream_type . "live") (preview (small . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-80x45.jpg") (medium . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-320x180.jpg") (large . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-640x360.jpg") (template . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-{width}x{height}.jpg")) (channel (mature . t) (status . "Sh*t Show Satyurday pewpew") (broadcaster_language . "en") (broadcaster_software . "") (display_name . "sodapoppin") (game . "C.H.A.S.E.D.") (language . "en") (_id . 26301881) (name . "sodapoppin") (created_at . "2011-11-22T04:40:56.75883Z") (updated_at . "2020-07-25T22:46:56.160721Z") (partner . t) (logo . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/5dc63b3a-5aee-4f6a-9b69-211341a22630-profile_image-300x300.png") (video_banner . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/7ed72b04-897e-4a85-a3c9-2a8ba74aeaa7-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.jpg") (profile_banner . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/sodapoppin-profile_banner-1c050aa5aed3558d-480.png") (profile_banner_background_color . "") (url . "https://www.twitch.tv/sodapoppin") (views . 322244612) (followers . 2752679) (broadcaster_type . "") (description . "Wtf do i write here? Click my stream, or i scream.") (private_video . :json-false) (privacy_options_enabled . :json-false))) ((_id . 5.449741660617762e+18) (game . "Dark Souls III") (broadcast_platform . "live") (community_id . "") (community_ids . []) (viewers . 5733) (video_height . 1080) (average_fps . 59) (delay . 0) (created_at . "2020-07-25T13:48:30Z") (is_playlist . :json-false) (stream_type . "live"))]))
```

I essentially want a way to isolate data and format it from the JSON being returned, I wanted to know how I could isolate: streamer name, the game being played, and perhaps the viewer count, and format it nicely in a table.

Is there perhaps a function or some sort of well documented elisp package that exists for formatting and extracting information from an alist file?

Comment: Alist is still list so usual list functions such as car, mapcar and elt works with alist, there is also assoc, alist-get and let-alist for alist only, for example, `(mapc (lambda (stream) (let-alist stream (message "%s is playing %s for %d viewers" .channel.name .game .viewers))) (alist-get 'streams my-data))`, let's assume `my-data` contains the alist you provided.

Answer (score 0):

So I modified the code with the recommendations provided, it now looks like:

```
(require 'request)
(setq twitch-client-id "XXX")
(setq twitch-oauth-token "XXX")

(setq xbuff (generate-new-buffer "*my output*"))

(request
 "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed"
 :sync t
 :headers '(
        ("Accept" . "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json")
        ("Client-ID" . "dsv0rf69bvzgi9ch6ys16vwncjax1z")
        ("Authorization" . "OAuth 8vnxkeckwenrrn461vjppls7olmg99"))
 :parser 'json-read
 :complete (cl-function
        (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
          (print (mapc (lambda (stream) (let-alist stream (message "%s is playing %s for %d viewers" .channel_name .game .viewers))) (alist-get 'streams data)) xbuff))))
          ;; (print data xbuff))))

(switch-to-buffer xbuff)
```

However the output send to xbuff now looks like:

```
[((_id . 2314860049) (game . "Fall Guys") (broadcast_platform . "live") (community_id . "") (community_ids . []) (viewers . 7026) (video_height . 1080) (average_fps . 59) (delay . 0) (created_at . "2020-07-26T05:47:43Z") (is_playlist . :json-false) (stream_type . "live") (preview (small . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_clintstevens-80x45.jpg") (medium . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_clintstevens-320x180.jpg") (large . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_clintstevens-640x360.jpg") (template . "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_clintstevens-{width}x{height}.jpg")) (channel (mature . t) (status . "fallguys pro") (broadcaster_language . "en") (broadcaster_software . "") (display_name . "ClintStevens") (game . "Fall Guys") ]
```

It seems to have removed the
`((streams .`  portion of the previous codes rendering of xbuff, and sadly did render something that resembles %s is playing %s for %d viewers.

Comment: I ended up getting this so somewhat run, but moving the print line to a seperate line under mapc

Comment: ```(print stream xbuff))))``` in an attempt to print the new alist of a new buffer, but it results in coming up with nil is streaming Terraria for 34 viewers.